# Accessing textures in PIXI.Filter fragment shader

Tags: glsl, webgl, pixi.js, webgl2

I'm trying to pass an image texture to my fragment shader (PIXI.Filter) but it won’t draw.

```js
const loader = PIXI.Loader.shared;
const KEY = 'testImg';
loader.add(KEY, testImg);

loader.load((loader, resources) => {
  const uniforms = {
    u_resolution: [this.app.screen.width, this.app.screen.height],
    u_texture0: resources[KEY].texture
  };

  const shader = new PIXI.Filter('', contourShader.frag, uniforms);
  this.app.stage.filters = [shader];

  console.log(resources[KEY].texture.valid); // true
});
```

```c
uniform sampler2D u_texture0;

void main(void) {
  vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture0, vTextureCoord);
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

`uSampler` will work fine for accessing the previous pass but ultimately I’ll want to draw stuff to a buffer and pass to the shader as a texture uniform.

Seems like you can only access uSampler in shaders invoked by that PIXI.Filter class, no other textures?

Comment: before this line: `const shader = new PIXI.Filter('', contourShader.frag, uniforms);` please add: `console.log(uniforms.u_texture0.valid);` . Its showing true or false? If its false then it means is not loaded yet. Related docs: https://pixijs.io/guides/basics/textures.html , https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Texture.html#valid

Comment: @domis86 thanks for the crucial tip! It still won't render anything, though. I've updated my code above with a proper loading technique.

Comment: Ok so i think you should post this question also in https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions

Comment: Ah, great, didn't know they had this. Thanks!